# Magento Modify Product Visibility For Some Products

Tags: php, magento

I want to add New product visibility option so product visible but only for direct URL. website visitors not able to find product / search product on website. if i send link to someone then he can see the product only.

i was thinking to create one hidden category and add product under this category and call block under cms page. please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple create a product

1. Set 'Visibility'  to 'Catalog'
2. Don't add the product to any category

Comment: if i have more then one product can this work with hidden category

Comment: It would, but there is no need to add them to a category unless you are trying to send customer to that category to view all these hidden products